# tooltip text is not visible in case of scrollable parent

Tags: css

I have to show tool tip on hover of an image which is inside scroll, because of which the content is not visible if I change the width it is hiding other seat images, what should be the way to achieve this

```
  <div class="plane-body" class="plane-seat valid-seat tooltip" >
  <div class="plane-seat invalid-seat available tooltip" *ngIf="!seat.validSeat">
       <span class="showpaxname invalid-seat-tooltip">{{
          'seatmap.unavailableSeatError.blockedSeat' | translate}}</span>
</div>
```

```
   .plane-body {
     margin: 3em;
     padding: 2em;
     overflow-y: auto;
      height: 70vh;
     overflow-x: hidden;
      min-height: 500px;
    }
  .tooltip .showpaxname::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: wheat transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .showpaxname {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

[image]

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Are you using any library to get this tooltip? Can you add a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide your code and create snippet

Comment: I am not using any library, I have shared the snippet

Comment: Try giving your .plane-seat class position relative, Hope it will work!

Comment: can you add raw HTML here

Answer (score 0):

Try to use left tooltip instead.

```
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  top: -5px;
  left: 105%; 
}
```

Comment: That won't work it will just move the tooltip to next seat map icon.

Comment: Try to change the position from absolute to relative